# ViewController transitions

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm building an iOS app that uses a lot of web services. 
The app has a `UItabBarController` as its root VC.

In one of my controllers I am pushing a viewController onto a `UINavigationController`. The ViewController that I am pushing onto the stack is a UITableViewController that has a `UITableView` with data from the web. I reinstaintiate the controller on each level the user goes down in the data. Then, right at the last level I call a web service and then want the whole `UITableViewController` to be dismissed and the original view controller to be shown.

This is how it looks:

`ViewControllerA` (UIViewController) -> user taps a Button - Push `ViewControllerB` onto it. (UINavigationController).

Once I am done with ViewControllerB I need it to be dismissed and ViewControllerA to be shown with the results.

In ViewControllerB I do something like this in NSNotification method:

```
if ([errorString hasPrefix:@"No descendants"]){
    UINavigationController *navigationController = 
                     [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
    BBSearchViewController *searchViewController = 
                     navigationController.viewControllers[0];
    searchViewController.categoryId = self.categoryId;


    if (searchViewController.brwosingCategoriesFromSearchPage){
        [[BBDataStore sharedDataStore]deRegisterForNotifications:self];
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

This causes this error in the console:

```
> 2014-05-08 09:32:16.306 TestApp[36948:60b] Finishing up a navigation transition 
in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.

 2014-05-08 09:32:16.780 TestApp[36948:60b] Unbalanced calls to begin/end 
appearance transitions for <ViewControllerA: 0xd08aa00>.
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you creating a new instance of `UITableViewController` on each table cell click ? Why not just reload table data and use one controller ?

Comment: Yes, I create a new instance on each cell click. I don't want to reload the data, as the user needs the ability to go back up the chain. So, Level 1 -> Level 2 - Level 3. Then, move back up the to Level 2 or 1 if they want to. Do you think it's the cause of my issues?

Comment: Try with only one view controller. When user clicks on a cell fetch next level data and reload table. Also keep track of the current level in a stack. When back button s clicked pop from the stack. stack is empty then pop the table view controller else you need to show previous level's data.

Comment: There are literally 100s of levels that the user can go through. The data set is pretty large. I'll try though. Thanks.

Comment: Then its better to keep only one ViewController. Its easier to handle that way.

Comment: Reloading the table view works. But it looks odd. Also I can't go up a level. I would need to recall the web service again for the last results one level up. Where previously I was just keeping it in memory. Its unlikely the user will load more than 5 instances of the UITableView controller. As that is as deep as it goes. When i said 100s of levels. I mean from level 1 - there are 34 level 2s. from each level 2 there are at leave 10 level 3's and so on. Keeping track would be hard I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting these errors because you're attempting one transition before another has finished. In your case, it looks like you're getting the notification before the view has finished appearing and then attempting to pop to root. You should be calling `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` using user input (when the user taps a button) or at least after `viewDidAppear:`.

Comment: The notification is called when I have data back from the web service. it is not triggered by the user. It is after this notification that I need to dismiss viewControllerB and show viewControllerA with the results. Where else should I use popToRootViewController?

Comment: It looks like you're getting the notification before the view has finished presenting. If you really want to do this, you should be asking the web service for the information after the transition has completed. Registering for the notification in `viewDidAppear` will accomplish this. But the effect you will have in some cases is that your view is immediately dismissed after it appears - is this the effect you want?

Comment: I'm not sure if I am understanding you correctly. Let me elaborate a little. I register view the notification in viewWillAppear on my viewControllerB. I get two notifications. One to tell me web service started another to tell me its finished. When I get the second web service notification on viewControllerB - I check the result and if there is nothing more to display in viewControllerB - I want viewControllerB to be dismissed and viewControllerA to appear - which will execute a new web service call, based on the data from viewControllerB. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you tried registering for notifications in `viewDidAppear` and not `viewWillAppear`? The transition hasn't finished in `viewWillAppear` and you're getting the second notification immediately after you register for it.

Comment: Yes. In viewDidApear it breaks the flow of the app. I can load one instance of viewControllerB - going to the next level means I can no longer get data and it remains empty (UITableView, that is)

Comment: Fixed it. You were on the right track. viewDidApear was called after I asked to go to viewControllerA. Which was the issue. Since I couldn't change the time when I get notifications - I set a bool value where I previously had popToRootViewController. After the notification message was done. viewDidAppear was called and if the BOOl was set - I popToRootViewController. This worked just fine - however do you think its an acceptable way of doing it?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by things like "going to the next level". A navigation controller holds a stack of view controllers. Typically you push a view controller onto the stack when the user taps something and then pop it off again when the user taps something else. Like the iPhone settings app. I have no idea why you want to dismiss the entire stack when you receive a notification. I also don't understand what the web service is, what starts it, and why you want this behaviour.

Comment: However, with that as a caveat, the method you propose would break if you only get one notification when the web service finishes and this comes after `viewDidAppear` is called. Then the boolean will never be set.